# I am facing problem in installing @truffle/hdwallet provider

Tags: npm

> ```
> PS C:\Coding\blockchain-toolkit> npm i @truffle/hdwallet-provider
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall spawn git
> npm ERR! path git
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
> npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t
> https://github.com/trufflesuite/provider-engine.git
> npm ERR! enoent
> npm ERR! enoent
> npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
> ```

Below are the details of my environment:

- Operating System:
  Ethereum client:
- Truffle version (v.5.1.4):
- node version (v12.14.0):
- npm version (6.13.4):

All these are the latest versions.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is git installed in your PC

If installed type this command in cmd `git --version`.

If it returns any version you are good. Otherwise:

go to system environment variables settings-> System variables-> Path-> paste your git path
Your git path -> C->program files->git->bin->click on address bar on top and copy the path and then paste in above process

Now apply the settings and then restart your PC.

Now open cmd and type `git--version`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the next command:

```
npm i @truffle/hdwallet-provider@next
```